# Trusted Web Activity/ Given CustomTabsIntent should be associated with a valid CustomTabsSession

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, chrome-custom-tabs

I have integrated Trusted Web Activity in my android app, when launching TwaLauncherActivity as main Activity, a blank white screen is displaying. I have followed, below GitHub link. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/tree/master/svgomg. Please suggest some solution, thanks in advance,

**TwaLauncherActivity.java**

```
    package com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TwaLauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TwaSessionHelper.TwaSessionCallback {

    private static final String TWA_ORIGIN = "https://dpm.therightdoctors.com";
    private static final String TARGET_URL = TWA_ORIGIN;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twa_launcher);

        Uri originUri = Uri.parse(TWA_ORIGIN);
        TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
        twaSessionHelper.setTwaSessionCallback(this);
        twaSessionHelper.bindService(this, originUri);

     /* TwaSessionHelper.TwaSessionCallback twaSessionCallback = twaSessionHelper.mTwaSessionCallback.get();
        if (twaSessionCallback != null) twaSessionCallback.onTwaSessionReady();*/
        // Set an empty transition from TwaLauncherActivity to the splash screen.
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = twaSessionHelper.createIntentBuilder()
                .setStartAnimations(this, 0, 0)
                .build();
        Uri openUri = Uri.parse(TARGET_URL);
        twaSessionHelper.openTwa(this, customTabsIntent, openUri);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
        twaSessionHelper.setTwaSessionCallback(null);
    }

    public void openTwa() {
        TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();

        // Set an empty transition from TwaLauncherActivity to the TWA splash screen.
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = twaSessionHelper.createIntentBuilder()
                .setStartAnimations(this, 0, 0)
                .build();

        Uri openUri = Uri.parse(TARGET_URL);
        twaSessionHelper.openTwa(this, customTabsIntent, openUri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwaSessionReady() {
        openTwa();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwaSessionDestroyed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwaOpened() {
        /*finishAndRemoveTask();*/
    }
}
```

**Debug catalog is showing below exception,**

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor/com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor.TwaLauncherActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given CustomTabsIntent should be associated with a valid CustomTabsSession
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)

Answer (score 0):

TWAs require the connection to the `CustomTabsService` to be established, and the code is trying to open the TWA before this is done.

On the `onCreate` method, the code is calling `bindService` and trying to open the TWA right after that call, before the connection is established and the session is ready (which happens asynchronously).

The correct thing to do is to open the CustomTab from `onTwaSessionReady` callback, to ensure the connection is established before opening the CustomTab.

The code should look like the following:

```
package com.therightdoctors.dpmdoctor;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TwaLauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements TwaSessionHelper.TwaSessionCallback {

private static final String TWA_ORIGIN = "https://dpm.therightdoctors.com";
private static final String TARGET_URL = TWA_ORIGIN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_twa_launcher);

    Uri originUri = Uri.parse(TWA_ORIGIN);
    TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
    twaSessionHelper.setTwaSessionCallback(this);
    twaSessionHelper.bindService(this, originUri);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
    twaSessionHelper.setTwaSessionCallback(null);
}

/**
  * This method is defined on the `TwaSessionHelper.TwaSessionCallback`
  * interface, which is implemented by the Activity.
  */
@Override
public void onTwaSessionReady() {
    TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
    // Set an empty transition from TwaLauncherActivity to the splash screen.
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = twaSessionHelper.createIntentBuilder()
            .setStartAnimations(this, 0, 0)
            .build();
    Uri openUri = Uri.parse(TARGET_URL);
    twaSessionHelper.openTwa(this, customTabsIntent, openUri);
    openTwa();
}

@Override
public void onTwaSessionDestroyed() {
}

@Override
public void onTwaOpened() {
    // call the below if you want the launcher activity to be 
    // removed from the task stack (eg: back button doesn't go back to it)
    /*finishAndRemoveTask();*/
}
}
```

Comment: thanks @ andreban , issue resolved now, but only blank white screen coming.  actually, TwaLauncherActivity.java is my main activity when app open it should load my website ( URL)  in android app.

Comment: Is there any log message showing where it stopped? Can you and Log.info calls to the code, to check if the callbacks are being invoked? Also, make sure you have Chrome Canary installed, as TWAs are not available in Chrome Stable yet.